# Prove that if A is idempotent and fullfills $A = A^{-1}$ then it follows that $A = I_n$

Tags: matrices, idempotents

I'm currently learning linear algebra and I have stumbled across the following example in my book without a solution.

A matrix $B \in \mathbb {R}^{n x n} $ is called idempotent if $BB = B$. Prove that if A is idempotent and fullfills $A = A^{-1}$ then it follows that $A = I_n$.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A = A^{-1}$ gives $A^2=I_n$. Since $A$ is idempotent, we have $A=A^2.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $AA^{-1}=I_n$ by definition.